# nginx reverse proxy get time-out response

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Am getting **The connection has timed out** after configuring a reverse proxy to some internal server.

Knowing that if i run wget i get 200 OK response and the correct page is downloaded.

```
[root@web1 nginx]# wget http://www.example.com:81
--2016-04-08 16:00:16--  http://www.example.com:81/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... ip-address
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|ip-address|:81... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1785 (1.7K) [text/html]
Saving to: قindex.htmlق

100%[=====================================================================================================================================================================>] 1,785       --.-K/s   in 0s

2016-04-08 16:00:16 (57.3 MB/s) - قindex.htmlق saved [1785/1785]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name localhost;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
        listen 80;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
        location @fallback {
            error_log /dev/null crit;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            access_log off ;
        }
    }
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*;
}
```

**Under /etc/nginx/vhost/*/exmaple.conf**

I have tried these two configurations:

```
server {
     server_name www.example.com;

     charset off;
     disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
     index index.php index.html;
     root $root_path;
     set $root_path /var/www/uexample/data/www/example.net;
     access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log ;
     error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log notice;
     include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssi on;
    listen 81;
}


server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/;
    }
    listen 81;
}
```

Comment: What is your nginx configuration?

Comment: Can you please post the configuration from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ?

Comment: @AlinAndrei i dont have such directory neither sites-available

Comment: @FadiAssaad ok, what about /etc/nginx/sites-available ?

Comment: As previously said i don't have such directories. I have different setup on my system. there is nginx.conf file that include vhosts conf files.

Comment: @AlinAndrei I have updated the post. Now it includes the main conf file (nginx.conf) and the two tested variations in example.conf under vhost.

Comment: @FadiAssaad thnx for the info, can you check the service on http://localhost:5601, from the server can you run nginx -t and telnet localhost 5601 ?

Comment: test is successful for nginx -t. I dont have telnet, but i concluded that the port is closed after i ran this: nc 127.0.0.1 5601 &> /dev/null; echo $? (port is closed when return value is 1) what does this means? iptables is disabled!!

Comment: @FadiAssaad It means that your app is not listening on 127.0.0.1, could you list netstat -antlp ?( run as sudo )

Comment: sorry the server listening on 5601 wasn't running for some reason. So after restart i ran again nc 127.0.0.1 5601 &> /dev/null; echo $? but with no response. Then i ran netstat -antlp : 0.0.0.0:81 LISTEN 
127.0.0.1:5601 LISTEN

Comment: When running nc 127.0.0.1 5601 &> /dev/null; echo $? do you get any input messages ? I tested with nginx and i had to input something to get 0, also would it be hard to install telnet ? "sudo apt-get install telnet ". I propose to test the 5601 service with lynx, "lynx http://localhost:5061/" to see it can be accessed.

Comment: also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29081732/1622779)

Comment: i have used the following combination of listen & server_name and it worked!! It stopped again when i changed the port into 81 !! Listen ip-address:80;
server_name subdomain.example.com;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As using port other than 80 is not possible (unknown reason) the workaround involved using a subdomain & listening to ip-address:port.

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    listen IP-Address:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    ssi on;
}
```

Comment: good work man :)